# Why are my NPCs disappearing, and chest loot too?

Tags: terraria

I Received a [Dryad](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) after killing the [Eye of Cthulhu](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu), but it's now gone. There's still proof that I killed the [Eye of Cthulu](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Eye_of_Cthulhu). The chair that made the [Dryad's](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dryad) house is gone too! Also, my [Goblin Tinkerer](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Goblin_Tinkerer) just disappeared too. And I still have the workshop. I have two chests at the top of my house which includes valuable things - everything inside it is gone! I am very confused. No other chests seem to have had anything happening too. What do I do?

Comment: It can't be a save issue because the furniture and your "Cthulhu proof" would be gone like the npcs. Unless they died there's no reason they should just disappear on their own. Are you playing on a server possibly? There's no real explanation based on the info you gave.

Comment: Did you not save properly? Is your NPC "homes" properly sealed?

Comment: are you by any chance playing on a server with other people ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you playing on mobile? If you are and you don't have auto-save on then you have to use "Save and exit" which is in the same menu as the beastiary and achievements. If you just force-exit the game your changes will not save.